# Best data structure for a file with unknown variable types

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, file-io, createprocess

My program reads in a file that is a list of program names followed by a comma and list of command line arguments for that program. I want to store each line separately so that I can sort them and then later run them. The problem I am having is trying to wrap my head around what to store the information as. I thought to make a struct or class but I don't know what the command line arguments will be or how many of them there will be. For example the file's first line might be notepad.exe, test.txt and the next line may be myprogram.exe, 10 2000.
what would be the best way to store an unknown number of arguements with an unknown data type?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should store the argument in a linked list so that you dont have to think about the number of arguments. Also you can store these arguments as strings or in character arrays as you dont have to worry about knowing the argument type any ways ...its the programs responsiblity..so myprogram.exe should know the arguments needs to be treated as numbers and notepad.exe should know arguments is a string which is the path of a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store each app name as the key of a `std::map` and the arguments as a `std::vector`

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> apps;
std::ifstream infile("apps.txt");

std::string line;
while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    std::string appName = getEverythingBeforeComma(line);
    std::vector<std::string> arguments = getEverythingAfterCommaAndSplitBySpace(line);

    apps[appName] = arguments;
}
```